# Mean value theorem application in trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I wanto to apply the mean value theorem to:

$$f(x)=(\sin(x))^2\cos(x) $$

in:
$$[0,π] $$

Applying the theorem:

$$\int_0^π (\sin(x))^2\cos(x) \, dx =π \sin(c)^2\cos(c) $$

Once i integrate:
$$ \frac{\sin^3(π)}{3}=π \sin(c)^2\cos(c)$$

It's correct? How can i find the $c$ value now?

Comment: $\sin(\pi) = $? and $\sin^{2} = 1 - \cos^{2}$

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Then just realize that $\sin(\pi)=0$. So we have
$$0=\pi\sin^2(c)\cos (c)\Rightarrow\sin^2(c)\cos(c)=0$$
From here we need either $\sin(c)$ or $\cos(c)$ to be zero. We have that sin is zero for
$$\sin(n\pi)=0\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi\right)=0\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
Thus we have that on the inteveral $[0,\pi]$ sin is zero for $c=0$ and $c=\pi$ and cosine is zero on the interval for $c=\pi/2$ thus
$$c\in\{0,\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\}$$